# I want the contents of table to fit as per the screen dynamically using simple html and css can any one helpin sorting it out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert date into table dynamically but the data is overflowing from the screen as the data will be in a single string i want to bind the data as per the screen size.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            height:100vh;
            width:100vh;
            overflow-x:hidden;
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>
                One
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
            </h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>two
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
            </h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

Then the long strings will go to the next line instead of overflowing.

Comment: SHOULD I SPECIFY IT FOR THE TABLE TAG OR BODY TAG ??

Comment: i would put it on the **table** so you dont accidently affect anything else outside of it